# Parent form method on child forms textbox event handler

Tags: c#, winforms, events, c#-4.0

I have like 100 text boxes spread out in 20 forms, all of them doing the same on EditValueChanged. 
These are  DevExpress.XtraEditors.TextEdit controls

```
ParentForm 
   ChildForm1
       TextBox1
       this.line1TextEditSubscriber.EditValueChanged += new System.EventHandler(PropertyEditValue);
       TextBox2
       this.line1TextEditSubscriber.EditValueChanged += new System.EventHandler(PropertyEditValue);
       TextBox3
       this.line1TextEditSubscriber.EditValueChanged += new System.EventHandler(PropertyEditValue);
       DropDow1
 ChildForm2
       TextBox1
       this.line1TextEditSubscriber.EditValueChanged += new System.EventHandler(PropertyEditValue);
       TextBox2
       this.line1TextEditSubscriber.EditValueChanged += new  System.EventHandler(PropertyEditValue);
       TextBox3
       this.line1TextEditSubscriber.EditValueChanged += new System.EventHandler(PropertyEditValue); 
       DropDow1



 public delegate void PropertyChangedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

//This one method is declared on the Parent Form.
         private void PropertyEditValue(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                  //Do some action 
                }
```

Is there a way I can access Parent form's PropertyEditValue method in each of the ChildForms Textboxe EditValueChanged

```
this.line1TextEditSubscriber.EditValueChanged += new System.EventHandler(PropertyEditValue);
```

Comment: What do you mean by `Parent form`, the `Parent form` should contain the child forms in its `Client area`, I think you mean `Owner form`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is have each of the child forms fire off their own event when any of their textboxes are edited:

```
public class ChildForm2 : Form
{
    private TextBox texbox1;
    public event EventHandler TextboxEdited;
    private void OnTextboxEdited(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        if (TextboxEdited != null)
            TextboxEdited(sender, args);
    }
    public ChildForm2()
    {
        texbox1.TextChanged += OnTextboxEdited;
    }
}
```

You could also put all of the textboxes into a collection so that you can add the handler in a loop, rather than writing that line 20 times:

```
var textboxes = new [] { textbox1, textbox2, textbox3};
foreach(var textbox in textboxes)
    texbox.TextChanged += OnTextboxEdited;
```

Then the parent form can subscribe to that event from each of the child forms, and fire its own event:

```
public class ParentForm : Form
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        ChildForm2 child = new ChildForm2();
        child.TextboxEdited += PropertyEditValue;
        child.Show();
    }
}
```

This allows the child class to "pass the event up" to the parent, so that it can handle the event, without the child class needing to know anything about the implementation of the type using it.  This child can now be used by any number of different types of parents, or it can be written before the specific implementations of the parent are all fixed/known (allowing a developer to work on each form independently) and means that the child form won't be "broken" as a result of changes to the parent.  The technical term for this is reducing coupling.

Answer (score 0):

Simply make it public and then pass an instance of the parent form to the child form

```
public void PropertyEditValue(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //Do some action 
}
```

or even more simple, if the function PropertyEditValue doesn't use any class variables, you can declare it `static` and access it directly like

```
this.line1TextEditSubscriber.EditValueChanged += ParentClass.PropertyEditValue
```